# parsing json multiple array with unknown field names with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json data that looks like this

```
    {  
   "projects":{  
      "COMMERCIAL":[  
         {  
            "ppID":"87",
            "pTitle":"5th Street Lofts"
         },
         {  
            "ppID":"94",
            "pTitle":"Skip-a-Long Child Development Services"
         }
      ],
      "CORPORATE":[  
         {  
            "ppID":"86",
            "pTitle":"Caxton Building"
         },
         {  
            "ppID":"68",
            "pTitle":"Swiss Valley Corporate Headquarters"
         }
      ],
      "EDUCATION (COLLEGIATE)":[  
         {  
            "ppID":"20",
            "pTitle":"Ashford University - Athletic Field"
         },
         {  
            "ppID":"64",
            "pTitle":"St. Ambrose University - Center For Health And Science Education"
         }
      ]
   },
   "error":"0"
}
```

In this example, "COMMERCIAL", "CORPORATE", and "EDUCATION (COLLEGIATE)" are unknown fields names.

I'm getting it from my CGI, which looks like this:

```
 $.ajax({    
        url: "cgi/myCGI.exe",    
        dataType: "json",           
        error: ajaxError,           
        success: function(json){   

            if(json.error !== "0"){                                                                 
                alert("error processing request: "+json.error);
                return;
            }

            var temp="";
            var i=0;
            for(i=0;i<=json.projects.length-1;i++){                     
                // tried something like this
            }

            $.each(json.projects, function(ppID, pTitle) {
                 // tried something like this
            });                 

             // add to my html

        }
  });
```

Ultimately, I want to add HTML to the webpage,
like

```
<div class="smSubTitle">COMMERCIAL</div> 
<a href="somePage.html?id=87">Fidlar Technologies</a><br>
<a href="somePage.html?id=94">Skip-a-Long Child Development Services</a><br>
<div class="smSubTitle">CORPORATE</div>
```

etc.

I can't figure out how to get the names of each project "sub title" then it's individual field values.

EDIT:
First, I noticed that json.projects.length is undefined.
I also tried json.projects[0].length but it is also undefined.

in

```
            $.each(json.projects, function(ppID, pTitle) {
                console.log("test: "+ppID);
                console.log("test: "+pTitle);
            });
```

ppID works, but pTitle says [object,object]

Comment: Please include what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`projects` property is an object and each object property contains an array. So you have to at first iterate through the object's keys and then the arrays, i.e. 2 nested loops:

```
var html = '', projects, type, i;

for ( type in json.projects ) {
    if ( json.projects.hasOwnProperty(type) ) {
       // append the type of the projects
       html += "<div class='smSubTitle'>" + type + "</div>";
       projects = json.projects[type];
       // iterate through each array
       for ( i = 0; i < projects.length; i++ ) {
            html += "<a href='somePage.html?id="+ projects[i].ppID+ "'>"+ projects[i].pTitle +"</a><br>";
       } 
    }
}
```

[Here is a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/gu8mq8fh/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a misunderstanding of what JSON is. JSON is a string and not an object hence it's abbreviation of **J**ava**S**cript **O**bject **N**otation. What you have is colloquially referred to as a POJO or **P**lain **O**ld **J**avascript **O**bject. They are different.

That said, you can iterate over these objects like so:

```
Object.keys(json.projects).forEach(function(key, i) {
  // key is "COMMERCIAL", "CORPORATE", ...
  // You can add the smSubTitle element here

  json.projects[key].forEach(function(item) {
    // item is an object {ppID: '...', pTitle: '...'}
    // You can add a link per object here
  });
});
```